# Why do preg_match with empty pattern always match

Tags: php, regex

I've a setting on database with a regex pattern to be passed to preg_match, but it can be empty resulting in `//` and passing this to `preg_match` with any string does a match.

For example:

```
 $m = preg_match( '//', 'something' );
 echo $m
 // output: 1
```

Why this behavior, and how to workaround ?

Comment: Not sure on *why*, but if you use `/^$/` you should be able to match only blank values.

Comment: Of course it will match anything. If you want to match empty string then use anchors `'/^$/'`

Comment: I have rolled back the edit that included the solution into the question. If you think your own solution adds something, then post it as an answer, see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern `//` imposes no restrictions on what can match it, so everything matches.

You could use the pattern `/^$/` (start of string is immediately followed by end of string).

You could test the pattern you are passing to see if it was `//`.